# How Tor network works

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, guard-node

I know that while you are using Tor, the exit relay and the middle node often change. Does the guard node also change, or does it stay the same until I close and restart Tor? When I click on "New identity" does the guard node change too?

Comment: What do you mean by access point?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "access point", but I'm assuming this is the one you are connecting to (an entry relay?) I think it does every time you restart tor or change identity.

Comment: I believe he means "guard node" by it. See my edit.